# Tagging Questionnaire Items with a Category

Tags: hl7-fhir

We have different categories of questions in our questionnaires: goals, observations, etc.. I am wondering what the best way to tag individual questions with these labels is. I am considering using Questionnaire.item.code and inserting something of the form **{"display": "observation"}**

E.g.

```
{
..
"item": [
  {
    "linkId": "LittleInterest",
    "code": [
      {
        "system": "http://loinc.org",
        "code": "44250-9"
      },
      {
        "display": "observation"
      }
    ],
    "text": "Little interest or pleasure in doing things",
    "type": "choice",
    "required": true,
    "answerValueSet": "http://loinc.org/vs/LL358-3"
  },
..
}
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way of capturing the question category at the question level?

Comment: What is your objective with the categorization?  Is it displayed to the person filling out the form?  Used somehow in form maintenance?

Comment: The main objective was to help categorize groups of questions. It is _not_ meant for the person filling out the form. It is meant to be used in form maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting 'computable' information in display is bad practice.  Display is intended for humans, not computation.  Also, item.code represents is supposed to refer to a code that represents the full meaning of the question (and 'display' is the official display name for that code).  So the meaning isn't what you want.

There's no "standard" way to categorize Questionnaire items.  Your best solution would be to define a custom extension.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was leaning towards too. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.